# C# SQL Connection String using Resources

Tags: c#, string, connection

I'm currently doing my final year university project using C# via Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2012 Management Studio. I'm having trouble trying work on my project at home due to connection to my SQL Server on my machine. In class we have set the connection string using Resources :

Name: `conStr`

Value: `Data Source = localhost;Initial Catalog = computer warehouse;Integrated Security = true`

And using

```
cnStr = Properties.Resources.conStr;
sqlCustomers = @"Select * from Customers";

daCustomer = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCustomers, cnStr);
cmdCustomers = new SqlCommandBuilder(daCustomer);

daCustomer.FillSchema(dsCustomer, SchemaType.Source, "Customers");
daCustomer.Fill(dsCustomer, "Customers");
```

In the form load

I have both SQL Server and Visual Studio on my Home Machine and have created the connection through Visual Studio, Created the Database on SQL and accuired the new Connection String

`Data Source=NIALL\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=computer warehouse;Integrated Security=True`

However when I run the program i'm getting this error

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information is telling me The server was not found or was not accessible

Any help is appreciated

Comment: If you don't have SQL express at home the connection string is wrong... Maybe you installed a different version?

Comment: I'm 99% sure they're the same versions, we were given the link to download from in class. Both Visual Studio and SQL Server are installed on my machine. This is something I really cant get my head around and will have to research some more

Comment: No worries, try: select @@version

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64) 
 Mar 29 2009 10:11:52 
 Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
 Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) Will i compare this to the one in uni?

Comment: Yes you can compare. Although it is the Express version so that part of the connection string should be fine.

Comment: Yeah I see, Well, thanks for your help Joe, Ill play about some more and read up on the problem

Comment: Have you checked that the database engine is configured to accept remote connections?

Comment: Yeah, i have done that, enabled TCP/IP etc, i followed a guide on one of the other comments

Comment: Checked that your firewall isn't blocking it?

Comment: Just checked, adding a new rule to allow the port, no joy

Comment: I got it, After doing all the things advised and with no joy, a computer restart and everything works fine, thanks your help. Good ol' restart

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the connection string is correct, because you're receiving an exception saying that the server isn't accessible.

Loading it from the resources shouldn't matter.
Place it in your code directly, and then make sure everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to help you figure out the correct connection string is to create a file with the UDL extension (ie connection.udl). Opening this will let you use a dialog to test your connection and then will give you the exact connection string to use. See here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1409.how-to-create-a-sql-connection-string-for-an-application-udl-file.aspx

Comment: I have tried this and used to string is provides, no joy, am i meant to replace the string in my Resources with the new string from the udl file?

Comment: Yes, if the connection test works, just take the new connection string from the udl file and replace what is in your Resource file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your Data Source setting in the connection string. If you only have one instance of SQL Server running on your home machine `localhost` should work, but if you need to refer to the server via the server instance name, make sure you have the **SQL Server Browser** service started for your instance. I think this is needed if you are referring to the data source using an instance name like `NIALL\SQLEXPRESS`.

Comment: SQL Server is running, I don't have SQL Server Browser Service in my list of services, I have tired localHost also, no joy

Answer (score 0):

I allowed the database to except remote connections, and following all the other advice - all it took then was a restart.